# Adding folders to your PATH environment variable

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, environment-variables, paths

Currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm trying to install [Ndless](http://ndless.me/)
and the SDK that goes with it so I can write programs in C and run them on my calculator. Anyways, I was wondering if somebody could explain the following step from the [installation guide](https://hackspire.org/index.php/C_and_assembly_development_introduction).

[image]

I am not very familiar with environment variables, but I assume

`[path_to_ndless]` is just a placeholder and you aren't meant to literally assign that to whatever `export PATH` is. My question then is, are you supposed to create the path then and there, or was it already created by running SDK's build_toolchain.sh script? If it's the latter, how do you see what the path is?

This is what my .bashrc file looks like. There is a single PATH variable at the bottom. Am I supposed to edit that specific variable with the required ndless folders, or do I create a new variable below it?

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi




# Private binaries
export PATH=$PATH:~/.bin
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Open a terminal with the keyboard command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Open *~/.bashrc* in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Add this line to the file:

   ```
   export PATH="[path_to_ndless]/ndless-sdk/toolchain/install/bin:[path_to_ndless]/ndless-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
   ```

   Here the `[path_to_ndless]` is simply the **path to where you droped the ndless-sdk** folder when you installed it. Remove that **placeholder text** and replace it with that path value. Say you placed that **git repo** in `/home/georgek/ndless` then your path to add into `~/.bashrc` would be:

   ```
   export PATH="/home/georgek/ndless-sdk/toolchain/install/bin:/home/georgek/ndless-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
   ```
4. Save the file and close gedit.
5. Now to get your environmental variables you just added to show in your currently opened terminal run the command:

   ```
    source ~/.bashrc
   ```

Please note several things:

- This `~/` means `/home/$USER`, where `$USER` mean **your username**, mine being **georgek**.
- So I could have also written `/home/georgek/.bashrc`

Comment: Do I need to add a separate PATH variable or do I just edit the one at the bottom underneath the line that says `# Private binaries` ?

Comment: Also, would this work? 
`export PATH="/home/nicholas/Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain/install/bin:/home/nicholas/Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain/../bin:${PATH}`

It's not the same as the prototype in the tutorial, but I got a terminal message after running the build_toolchain.sh script that said "don't forget to add these files to your environment variables", and they were in this format.

Comment: Please add it undér that line you referred to and source the file.